# how to access to exchange properties in brightway

Tags: brightway

Ecoinvent has defined *exchange properties* such as wet mass, carbon content and so on. Are these properties available when the database is loaded in Brightway? if so how should we access them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exchange properties are not extracted in [the current code](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-io/src/ef6db3e9e02504f872cc143b39b0da907a6ab9ef/bw2io/extractors/ecospold2.py#lines-286). They will be added in the next six months, as they are needed for another project. You can speed this up by submitting a pull request!

Comment: a pull request proposing a set of modifications in the code to do it? I'll need to get my hands into the parsing code sooner than later.